# Replacing values with 'NA' by ID in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have data that looks like this

```
ID    v1    v2
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     1     0
3     0     1
4     0     1
```

I want to replace all values with 'NA' if the ID occurs more than once in the dataframe. The final product should look like this

```
ID    v1    v2
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     NA    NA
3     NA    NA
4     0     1
```

I could do this by hand, but I want R to detect all the duplicate cases (in this case two times ID '3') and replace the values with 'NA'.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `duplicated()` from either end, and then replace.

```
idx <- duplicated(df$ID) | duplicated(df$ID, fromLast = TRUE)
df[idx, -1] <- NA
```

which gives

> ```
>   ID v1 v2
> 1  1  1  0
> 2  2  0  1
> 3  3 NA NA
> 4  3 NA NA
> 5  4  0  1
> ```

This will also work if the duplicated IDs are not next to each other.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), v1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), v2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "v1", 
"v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 3):

One more option:

```
df1[df1$ID %in% df1$ID[duplicated(df1$ID)], -1] <- NA
#> df1
#  ID v1 v2
#1  1  1  0
#2  2  0  1
#3  3 NA NA
#4  3 NA NA
#5  4  0  1
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), v1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), v2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "v1", 
"v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method

```
# get list of repeated IDs
repeats <- rle(df$ID)$values[rle(df$ID)$lengths > 1]

# set the corresponding variables to NA
df[, -1] <- sapply(df[, -1], function(i) {i[df$ID %in% repeats] <- NA; i})
```

In the first line, we use `rle` to extract repeated IDs. In the second, we use `sapply` to loop through non-ID variables and replace IDs that repeat with NA for each variable.

Note that this assumes that the data set is sorted by ID. This may be accomplished with the `order` function. (`df <- df[order(df$ID),]`).

If the dataset is very large, you might break up the first function into two steps to avoid computing the `rle` twice:

```
dfRle <- rle(df$ID)
repeats <- dfRle$values[dfRle$lengths > 1]
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="ID    v1    v2
1     1     0
2     0     1
3     1     0
3     0     1
4     0     1")
```